# Flash AS3 unload loaded SWF completely

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

how do i absolutely and completely unload a loaded SWF.

Here's the case. I have two different SWF, both have the same movieClips in the library with the same name and instance...but...both have different shape. So basically both are different but the names.

So i loaded the first.swf into the main.swf, in the first.swf contains button that order the loaded in the main.swf to unloadAndStop() and load the second.swf. But somehow the objects in the second.swf take the shape in the first.swf.

I hit the wall with this. How do i completely unload the first.swf

Thx guys

Answer (score 0):

Try to load child swfs (`first.swf` and `second.swf`) into child application domains of the current application domain (`Usage C` in this Article [Working with application domains](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd75bf4610ec9e22f43855da312214da1d8f-8000.html), you can also find code sample from this article below). With this technique you'll get:

1. separate classes (all classes) of `first.swf` and `second.swf` from each other
2. unload all the class definitions for garbage collection after unloading swf

AS3 from the article:

```
var appDomainC:ApplicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain); 

var contextC:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, appDomainC); 
var loaderC:Loader = new Loader(); 
loaderC.load(new URLRequest("module3.swf"), contextC);
```

Comment: How do i unload the classes? Sorry i'm still new with this thing

Comment: classes of _first.swf_ will not be accessible by the _second.swf_ by default when you load them into separate app domains. And you can't _unload_ classes of _first.swf_ explicitly, you can just unload swf and all it's classes will be garbage collected later.